# javaCV detectMultiScale with LBP cascade does not work on physical device

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection, javacv

My Android application uses javaCV and calls detectMultiScale() function with LBP cascade to detect faces. It works completely fine on my emulator. However, when I tried to test it on my HTC Incredible S, it returns 0, could not detect any face! Could anyone show me some hints why it does not work? Many thanks for your help!!!

Here is my code for face detection:

```
    CASCADE_FILE = working_Dir.getAbsolutePath() + "/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml";

    public static CvRect getFaceWithLBP(IplImage grayFaceImg)
    {
         CascadeClassifier cascade = new CascadeClassifier(CASCADE_FILE);
         CvRect facesdetection = new CvRect(null);

         cascade.detectMultiScale(grayFaceImg, facesdetection, 1.1, 2, CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT | CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH, 
                             new CvSize(), new CvSize(grayFaceImg.width(), grayFaceImg.height()));  

         return facesdetection;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a note, as per [the OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html?highlight=detectmultiscale#void%20CascadeClassifier%3a%3adetectMultiScale%28const%20Mat&%20image,%20vector%3CRect%3E&%20objects,%20double%20scaleFactor,%20int%20minNeighbors,%20int%20flags,%20Size%20minSize,%20Size%20maxSize%29), the flags (such as CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT | CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH) can not be used with new cascades (like LBP ones).

> void CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale(const Mat& image, vector& objects, double scaleFactor=1.1, int minNeighbors=3, int flags=0, Size minSize=Size(), Size maxSize=Size())
>   Parameters:
>
> - **cascade** – Haar classifier cascade (OpenCV 1.x API only). It can be loaded from XML or YAML file using Load(). When the cascade is not needed anymore, release it using cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade(&cascade).
> - **image** – Matrix of the type CV_8U containing an image where objects are detected.
> - **objects** – Vector of rectangles where each rectangle contains the detected object.
> - **scaleFactor** – Parameter specifying how much the image size is reduced at each image scale.
> - **minNeighbors** – Parameter specifying how many neighbors each candidate rectangle should have to retain it.
> - **flags** – Parameter with the same meaning for an old cascade as in the function cvHaarDetectObjects. ***It is not used for a new cascade.***
> - **minSize** – Minimum possible object size. Objects smaller than that are ignored.
> - **maxSize** – Maximum possible object size. Objects larger than that are ignored.

Comment: About not being able to locate faces, you can try "**new CvSize(0, 0)**" instead of "**new CvSize()**".

Comment: why flags is not used for a new cascades? what is alternative?

Comment: The only defined flags are all tweaks for the algorithm for Haar cascades: http://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d31/group__objdetect__c.html. LBP cascades do not use these options.